# Sorting people into team values from large Data Set

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is supposed to sort employees, designated on another page, into simplified categories for their team names with managers being marked with an "m" at the end. Due to conflicting teams in the same row, a number of logical rules had to be applied to simplify the different rows into a single team value. The IF-THEN statements have stopped working and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub Team_Clean()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    
    Dim ColumnNumber, i, i2, i3, Maxval As Variant
    
    Dim Myfind, Myrep As String
    
    Set SrchRng = SH_Data.Range("L2:L9999")
        
    SH_Data.Range("T2:T9999").Value = ""
    For i2 = 1 To 3
        Select Case i2
            Case 1:
            ColumnNumber = 12
            Case 2:
            ColumnNumber = 14
            Case 3:
            ColumnNumber = 15
        End Select
        
        Maxval = SH_Cal.Cells(2, 11).Value
        
        For i3 = 1 To Maxval
        
        Myfind = SH_Cal.Cells(1 + i3, 9).Value
        Myrep = SH_Cal.Cells(1 + i3, 10).Value
        
        SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:=Myfind, Replacement:=Myrep, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        Next i3
            
            For Each cel In SH_Data.Range("L2:L9999").Cells
            
                If InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -11).Value, "-NL") Then
                    cel.Value = "POB"
                End If
            
                If InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -11).Value, "-ROC") Then
                    cel.Value = "ROCAT"
                End If
    
                If cel.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C19" And InStr(1, cel.Value, "POBM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, "POBM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, "POBM") Then
                    cel.Value = "POB"
                End If
        
                If cel.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C19" And InStr(1, cel.Value, "DCS/PRPM") Then
                    cel.Value = "DCS/PRP"
                End If
        
                If cel.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C19" And InStr(1, cel.Value, "OISBM") Then
                    cel.Value = "OISB"
                End If
        
                If cel.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C19" And InStr(1, cel.Value, "OISBM") And Not InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, "POBM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, "POBM") Then
                    cel.Value = "OISB"
                End If
             
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DARSM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, "DARSM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -7).Value, "DARSM") And InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -6).Value, "Tableau") And Not InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, "DCS/PRP") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, "DCS/PRPM") Then
                    cel.Value = "DARS"
                End If
            
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DARSM") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, "DARSM") Then
                    cel.Value = "DARS"
                End If
            
                If InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -11).Value, "STA269") Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, -11).Value, "STA266") Then
                    cel.Value = "DARS"
                End If
     
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DARSM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "DARS" Then
                    cel.Value = "DARS"
                End If
            
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "OISBM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "OISB" Then
                    cel.Value = "OISB"
                End If
       
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "POBM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "POB" Then
                    cel.Value = "POB"
                End If
        
                If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DCS/PRPM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "DCS/PRP" Then
                    cel.Value = "DCS/PRP"
                End If
            Next
            
        For i = 1 To 4
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="DARSM", Replacement:="DARS", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="OISBM", Replacement:="OISB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="DCS/PRPM", Replacement:="DCS/PRP", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="POBM", Replacement:="POB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
    Next
        For i = 1 To 4
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="ROCAT;#ROCAT", Replacement:="ROCAT", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="OISB;#OISB", Replacement:="OISB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="DCS/PRP;#DCS/PRP", Replacement:="DCS/PRP", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="DARS;#DARS", Replacement:="DARS", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            SH_Data.Columns(ColumnNumber).Replace What:="POB;#POB", Replacement:="POB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i
        
    Next i2
    
        
    Set SrchRng = SH_Data.Range("A2:A9999")
    
    For Each cel In SrchRng.Cells
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "STA") >= 1 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Standardized"
        End If
        
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DARSM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "DARS" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "DARS"
        End If
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "OISBM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "OISB" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "OISB"
        End If
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "POBM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "POB" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "POB"
        End If
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DCS/PRPM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "DCS/PRP" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "DCS/PRP"
        End If
    Next
    
    
    Set SrchRng = SH_Data.Range("L2:L9999")
    
    For Each cel In SrchRng.Cells
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = cel.Value
        Else
            cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = cel.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
        If cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" And cel.Value = "" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = cel.Offset(0, 3)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you expound upon _stopped working_ ? It would help if you could explain what the logic should do and what it is doing instead. A few example texts with expected and actual outputs would be nice too.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. When I say "Stopped Working" I mean that at one point they did their expected functions but later they stopped. No error code, they simply stopped performing the function. 

'''' If InStr(1, cel.Value, "DARSM") And cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "DARS" Then
                    cel.Value = "DARS"
                End If
''''

As for the function, the one above is supposed to sense if there is a manager in one column and a single normal team member in another - and then re-assign the manager column to the shared team value.

Answer (score 1):

When combining `And` and `Or` in the same statement you probably always want to add parentheses to ensure it works as you intended.

Eg: this might be more what you meant:

```
If cel.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C19" And (InStr(1, cel.Value, "POBM") _
                                      Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, "POBM") _
                                      Or InStr(1, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, "POBM")) Then
  
     cel.Value = "POB"

End If
```

Also you're testing the same cell values and offsets over and over, so consider assigning those to variables before you start testing - it will make your code much easier to read/maintain.